# display a view in ios without overwrapped view

Tags: ios, xcode, view

In the following code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
    if(!first)
    {
        [self display];
    }
}

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [self display];
}


-(void) display
{
    [self addsubview:a];
    [self addsubview:b];
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I initialize view1. First, in `-viewDidLoad` the `-display` method adds view a and b.
Then I move to another view and come back to this view1, so `-viewWillAppear` is called.
So view a, view b are added again and view1 has views a and b twice.

I want to have view a and b just once.

How can I make the view state like it was before `-viewDidLoad` runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you can remove your subviews in `-viewWillDisappear`:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [a removeFromSuperview];
    [b removeFromSuperview];
}
```